# VLookup Displaying Duplicate Values - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, data-manipulation

I've created a lookup formula to take values from column E, match them with values in column A, and assign the corresponding value found in column C and populate it in column F.

I've checked for duplicates in E and A, but I'm still seeing duplicates in F. It's not because there isn't a match, I've checked that as well.

My formula is:
=LOOKUP(E2, $A$2:$A$121, $C$2:$C$121)

Here is a simplified version of the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A-S0nHFIUGycaDo7KDPAzWBwRZQmfxkjaMivwGfBh-8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

delete everything in F column and use in F2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E, A:C, 3, 0)))
```

Comment: Do you mean use that formula instead of what I have currently?

Comment: @VictoriaHood yes

Comment: @VictoriaHood https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MqWsG5vkvsqfdhzaDkQ8z002Lej8BXKS_-2qsuy8Veo/edit#gid=0

Comment: @player0 you really gotta start using ARRAYFORMULA instead of INDEX() on these!